# Can an indexer parameter ever be null?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, indexer

This is a code from a class of mine with a custom [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/):

```
public string this[string key]
{
    get => /* ... */;
    set
    {
        if (key != null) doSomething(key, value);
    }
}
```

Now ReSharper underlines the `key != null` check and says:

> Expression is always true.

While I do believe ReSharper is correct here, I cannot understand why.

Maybe [the language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#indexers) enforces this?

**My question:**

Can an indexer parameter ever be null?

**Update 1:**

Before deleting my question because of me being too dumb, just a note on why ReSharper wrote the warning:

I derived my class from `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` which seems to be annotated by ReSharper to not have `null` for the indexer parameter.

Thus, the warning. Sorry for posting such a non-question.

Comment: _"I do believe ReSharper is correct here"_ -- why do you believe that? it would have been easy enough for you to check, and you'd have found it's not. That is assuming, of course, that you've shown us every pertinent detail.

Comment: R# seems to be incorrect here. However an indexer *shouldn´t* be null, but surely it *can*.

Comment: Good point, @PeterDuniho Should I delete my question here?

Comment: I do not get this resharper warning (v 2017.2)

Comment: Well, it seems to be a non-question. Asking "why?" about something that isn't true in the first place doesn't seem useful to me.

Comment: What's the point of editing your question from a non-question to something you can trivially check yourself? _"Can an indexer parameter ever be null?"_ -- of course it can. You could've just passed `null` to see yourself.

Comment: I still do not understand, why ReSharper suggests this.

Comment: Make a support request, and share their answer ith us

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why ReSharper seems so sure that the expression is always true, since you *can* pass null to an indexer. However, if you have two indexers that accept reference types, indexing null would be ambiguous unless the null is cast. Perhaps ReSharper doesn't account for the fact that you can still cast null, and so instead assumes that you can never pass null to an indexer, which, again, has been shown to be untrue.

Comment: I've just added an update to my question. Seems to be because I derived from `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: @Uwe Keim: Ah, so ReSharper doesn't emit a warning when your type doesn't implement IDictionary<,>? If so, I'll delete my answer and you can self-answer, though that does still leave the question of whether your question should have an MCVE (and if it did, you surely would have spotted the error).

Comment: Yes, just checked. When not deriving from `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, no warning occurs.

Comment: I'm deleting the question, too now :-) Oops, seems that I'm unable to delete.

Comment: @Uwe Keim: You unaccept my answer, I delete my answer, and then you can delete your question :) (Or I could just delete your question for you right now, but that would count as a moderator deletion.)

Comment: Or you let it stand, as a question about Resharper.